# How to convert List of Dictionary to simple 2D list in python to perform the specific task?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list which looks something like this :

```
myList = [{'email_address': 'abc@gmail.com', 'status': 'subscribed'}, {'email_address': 'def@live.com', 'status': 'subscribed'}, {'email_address': 'ghi@gmail.in', 'status': 'pending'}, {'email_address': 'jkl@gmail.com', 'status': 'subscribed'}, {'email_address': 'mno@gmail.com', 'status': 'pending'}, {'email_address': 'pqr@yahoo.com', 'status': 'pending'}, {'email_address': 'stu@gmail.com', 'status': 'pending'}, {'email_address': 'vwx@y.com', 'status': 'pending'}, {'email_address': 'yz@z.com', 'status': 'pending'}]
```

I want to convert the list of the dictionary into a simple list as I don't require the 'email_address' and 'status' labels. I want the list to look something like this:

```
newList = [['abc@gmail.com', 'subscribed'], ['def@live.com', 'subscribed'], ['ghi@gmail.in', 'pending'], ['jkl@gmail.com', 'subscribed'], and so on...]
```

How do I convert the list as described?

And also after converting to this list how do I store the email addresses with 'subscribed' as the second field in one list and 'pending' as the second field in another list. For example:

```
subscribedList = ['abc@gmail.com', 'def@gmail.com', 'jkl@gmail.com' and so on...]
pendingList = ['ghi@gmail.com', 'mno@gmail.com', 'pqr@gmail.com' and so on...]
```

As I'm new to python I find conversions from list difficult please do help me out.

Note: 1. The `myList` is coming from an API and cannot be changed.

2. I have used the dummy email addresses like `abc@gmail.com` for illustration purpose only. The real Email addresses are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension and the `dict.values` to get only values.

**Ex:**

```
myList = [{'email_address': 'abc@gmail.com', 'status': 'subscribed'}, {'email_address': 'def@live.com', 'status': 'subscribed'}, {'email_address': 'ghi@gmail.in', 'status': 'pending'}, {'email_address': 'jkl@gmail.com', 'status': 'subscribed'}, {'email_address': 'mno@gmail.com', 'status': 'pending'}, {'email_address': 'pqr@yahoo.com', 'status': 'pending'}, {'email_address': 'stu@gmail.com', 'status': 'pending'}, {'email_address': 'vwx@y.com', 'status': 'pending'}, {'email_address': 'yz@z.com', 'status': 'pending'}]
print( [i.values() for i in myList] )
```

**Output:**

```
[['subscribed', 'abc@gmail.com'], ['subscribed', 'def@live.com'], ['pending', 'ghi@gmail.in'], ['subscribed', 'jkl@gmail.com'], ['pending', 'mno@gmail.com'], ['pending', 'pqr@yahoo.com'], ['pending', 'stu@gmail.com'], ['pending', 'vwx@y.com'], ['pending', 'yz@z.com']]
```

2nd Que

```
for i in myList:
    if i["status"] == 'subscribed':
        subscribedList.append(i["email_address"])
    else:
        pendingList.append(i["email_address"])
print(subscribedList)
print(pendingList)
```

**Output:**

```
['abc@gmail.com', 'def@live.com', 'jkl@gmail.com']
['ghi@gmail.in', 'mno@gmail.com', 'pqr@yahoo.com', 'stu@gmail.com', 'vwx@y.com', 'yz@z.com']
```

Comment: I'm getting output something like this:  `[dict_values(['abc@gmail.com', 'subscribed']), dict_values(['def@live.com', 'subscribed']), dict_values(['ghi@gmail.in', 'pending']), dict_values(['jkl@gmail.com', 'subscribed'])]`

Comment: Use `d = [list(i.values()) for i in myList]`

Answer (score 1):

```
newList = [list(item.values()) for item in myList]
#>>>[['abc@gmail.com', 'subscribed'], ['def@live.com', 'subscribed'], ['ghi@gmail.in', 'pending'], ['jkl@gmail.com', 'subscribed'], ['mno@gmail.com', 'pending'], ['pqr@yahoo.com', 'pending'], ['stu@gmail.com', 'pending'], ['vwx@y.com', 'pending'], ['yz@z.com', 'pending']]

subscribedList = [item.get("email_address") for item in myList if item.get("status") == "subscribed"]
#>>>['abc@gmail.com', 'def@live.com', 'jkl@gmail.com']

pendingList = [item.get("email_address") for item in myList if item.get("status") == "pending"]
#>>>['ghi@gmail.in', 'mno@gmail.com', 'pqr@yahoo.com', 'stu@gmail.com', 'vwx@y.com', 'yz@z.com']
```